# weights used by caffe layers with same name in different phases

Tags: caffe

I have a prototxt like:

```
layer{
  name:"l1"
  bottom: "b1"
  top: "t1"
  include{
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
layer{
  name:"l1"
  bottom: "b1"
  top: "t2"
  include{
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

There are two layers with 
**same name

different blobs

different phase**

**What will be the weights used in test phase?**
1.) weights learned in train phase(because the layers have same name)
2.) Random initial weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weights learned in train phase will be attempted to be used in test phase.

But errors will occur to stop the testing if any of the 2 conditions below isn't satisfied:

1. the numbers of the two layers's blobs are equal
2. the shapes(size at every dimension) of the two layers's blobs are consistent

In fact, the layer in testing net will always try to copy weights from the layer with the same name in trained net and check on the number and shape of the blob containing weights to make sure that it will use the proper weights.

Details can be found in ["template 
void Net::ShareTrainedLayersWith(const Net* other)"](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/net.cpp) function that will be called by test net object to copy weights from the trained net at the begining of test.